# Add Django pytest test database migrations only for tests

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration, pytest-django

I am looking for a decent solution for any migrations in database itself.

We have custom SQL script which adds `pg_trgm` extention to PostgreSQL database, which is simply

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

and

```
FROM postgres:14.5-alpine
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

in database`s Dockerfile

After that I can easily add specialized GIN indexes to models, i.e.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    """
    My model comment
    """

    objects = MyManager()

    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            models.Index(Upper("field"), name="field_idx"),
            GinIndex(
                fields=["field"],
                opclasses=["gin_trgm_ops"],
                name="field_gin_idx",
            ),
            GinIndex(
                OpClass(Upper("field"), name="gin_trgm_ops"),
                name="field_gin_idx",
            ),
```

So I want to reflect that "custom script" in Django pytest tests.

P.S.: I know there is a [trigram extention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#trigramextension) for that purpose, but it was a TL decision to put custom database migration in separate place

Do you have any idea on how to prepare such fixture?

I was looking for related pytest fixtures but haven't found any solution